# birt ChartException caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: charts, nullpointerexception, birt

I have birt report deployed to our server. I am getting the exception mentioned above on some pages but not all. I figured null means maybe there's no data but I made sure and checked triple times that there is. What must be causing this error? Any idea?

Here is the stack trace.

```
The following items have errors:

Chart (id = 706):
-
null ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLListingBandLM.intializeHeaderContent(HTMLListingBandLM.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLListingBandLM.initialize(HTMLListingBandLM.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.initialize(HTMLTableBandLM.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLayoutManagerFactory.createLayoutManager(HTMLLayoutManagerFactory.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.createLayoutManager(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLGroupLM.layoutChildren(HTMLGroupLM.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLGroupLM.layoutChildren(HTMLGroupLM.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1537)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.doExecution(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1912.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1907.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.irondata.icm.server.servlet.filters.IcmSessionFilter.doFilter(IcmSessionFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.chart.exception.ChartException
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.render(Generator.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.renderToImageFile(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1023)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.extension.render.Bar.renderSeries(Bar.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.AxesRenderer.renderPlot(AxesRenderer.java:2279)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.AxesRenderer.render(AxesRenderer.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.render(Generator.java:1301)
    ... 110 more
```

here is an excerpt from the birt error log I got from test server. I noticed though that it started acting like that when I added this script (I already added null checker, just incase it was the cause)

```
function beforeDrawDataPointLabel( dph, label, icsc )
{
 seriesVal = dph.getSeriesValue()
 insetLabel = label.getInsets();
 if(seriesVal=="Opening Assessment")
 {
  if(insetLabel!=null)
  {
    insetLabel.setTop(0)
    insetLabel.setBottom(0)
    insetLabel.setLeft(0)
    insetLabel.setRight(0)
  }
 }
 else if (seriesVal=="Last Assessment")
 {
  if(insetLabel!=null)
  {
    insetLabel.setTop(0)
    insetLabel.setBottom(0)
    insetLabel.setLeft(0)
    insetLabel.setRight(0)
  }
 }
    if(label!=null)
        label.setInsets(insetLabel)
//4 is NA while 5 is 0, this is a workaround for the labels to come up in the chart. zero val does not show labels/bar
if(dph.getOrthogonalValue()!=null || dph.getOrthogonalValue()!='')
{
     if( dph.getOrthogonalValue() == 4 ){
    if(label!=null){
        label.getCaption().setValue("N/A");
        label.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
      else if(dph.getOrthogonalValue() == 5 ){
      if(label!=null)
      {
        label.getCaption().setValue("0");

        label.setVisible(true);
        }

        } else{
         label.setVisible(false);
        }
  }
}
```

error log: (not very helpful for me.)

```
    Jan 3, 2014 4:03:16 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor processExtendedContent
SEVERE: null
org.eclipse.birt.chart.exception.ChartExceptionJan 3, 2014 4:03:16 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor processExtendedContent
SEVERE: null
org.eclipse.birt.chart.exception.ChartException
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.render(Generator.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.renderToImageFile(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1023)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLListingBandLM.intializeHeaderContent(HTMLListingBandLM.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLListingBandLM.initialize(HTMLListingBandLM.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.initialize(HTMLTableBandLM.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLayoutManagerFactory.createLayoutManager(HTMLLayoutManagerFactory.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.createLayoutManager(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLGroupLM.layoutChildren(HTMLGroupLM.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLGroupLM.layoutChildren(HTMLGroupLM.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.runReport(BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.__execute(AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleChangeParameter(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1907.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.irondata.icm.server.servlet.filters.IcmSessionFilter.doFilter(IcmSessionFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Are you only getting the error on pages with charts?

Comment: Hi, nope. the error occurs only on some pages. Ex. the report consists of 10 pages (chart is grouped by), 9 out of 10 displays right while 10th displays error. I managed to get the chart error log but still it doesn't give me a clue what could be causing it. see update. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing a line from my script. Apparently, the `label.setVisible(true)` or false was causing this error. Since I still need to hide the label, I just created a workaround and set the caption value to "" instead. Code is

```
label.getCaption().setValue("");
```

Btw, can anyone tell me why the label.setVisible() was making the error? I am confused. Most of the tutorial I read were coded like that, even on the sample documentation.